# Libreoffice unoconv hangs when conversion process started

Tags: server, python, libreoffice

I am working on an application, in which I am using `unoconv` for converting `ppt` and `doc` files. It is working on `localhost`, where I have an X server, but on ubuntu-server, it hangs up. As I read on the net, it's LibreOffice which is giving problem, as it hangs.

When I `ctrl+C` it, I get the following error:

```
unoconv -f pdf terminal.ppt 
^Cunoconv: SystemError during export phase: Couldn't instantiate python representation of structered UNO type com.sun.star.lang.DisposedException
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/unoconv", line 1053, in <module>
    die(exitcode)
  File "/usr/bin/unoconv", line 919, in die
    if convertor.desktop.getCurrentFrame():
uno.RuntimeException: illegal object given!
```

Output of `which libreoffice` :

```
/usr/bin/libreoffice
```

I don't have a UI or desktop environment on server. What is going wrong?

Comment: Tried it on my Ubuntu, and no problem. Created a test ppt file, runned the exact same command, and it turned the ppt file to a pdf. Which version of Ubuntu and unoconv are you using

Comment: @blade19899 : It's a server edition. On regular Ubuntu it's no problem.

Comment: How long did you wait before doing `CTRL`-`C`?

Comment: @blade19899 : I guess 1-2 mins.. And, the document is  just 125kb, takes about 2 seconds on desktop. This problem is of libreoffice is what I am sure about.

Comment: Is it installed? `unoconv` is not Installed by default on my Ubuntu 14.04 server? could you post the output of `whereis unoconv`

Comment: @blade19899 : Yes, it is installed, `/usr/bin/unoconv` .  The process wouldn't have started if it was not.

Comment: Did you get the solution for your problem ? @WeareBorg

Comment: @AnkurSharma : I simply started using LibreOffice directly...headless version of it works. :-)